# I brought My Macbook Pro last year in november (Latest Model available then) and suddenly today started to show a question mark?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery

I brought My Mac-book Pro last year in November(Latest Model available then) and suddenly today started to show a question mark?

I tried to pull up the option menu by holding <kbd>Option</kbd> key while booting but now I came up with a online recovery. What happened to my data on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a folder icon with a question mark? That means it can't find the operating system to boot from!

Generally speaking, this would indicating a failing hard drive. There is a possibility you have lost some data. However, it could be just a case that some of the files have been 'misplaced'.

The best way to get on top of this would be to immediately run Internet Recovery and/or use Disk Utility to try and repair your computer.

See:

- [Mountain Lion - OS X Recovery](http://www.apple.com/au/osx/recovery/)
- [HT4718 OS X: About OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718)

Comment: The hard drive and data (most of it anyway) may be okay (hopefully) it may be that the booting sequence can't find the Finder or there are corrupted files on the disk. Either way, you're right, using Apple's recovery mode and then disk utility will help sort that out.

Comment: When you're done, you really should backup your system to another storage device. They are not expensive and take a lot of worry out of using computers. Also, if you are uncomfortable with the advice given here, take your system to an Apple facility and let them fix it. You should still be under warranty.

Comment: Now see what happened to me.. I took it to near by Apple Customer care and he said that my hard drive is making annoying sound may be the blade which is present over the discs is misplaced and we can't do anything. As i am under warranty he ordered a new hard drive for me... but no way to regain my data. He said it would cost 1500$ if you really want to get data from out of it...

Comment: Data recovery can be a very expensive option, with no guarantee on what they would be able to get back